# Long MYSQL query execution

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with a query that needs to monitor the state warehouse, input, output, debt, discharge ...

**Query:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(ulaz.sifra, ' - ', ulaz.uredjaj) AS uredjaj,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ulaz.mac) AS kolicinaUlaza,
       COUNT(DISTINCT izlaz.mac) AS kolicinaIzlaza,
       COUNT(DISTINCT povracaj.mac) AS kolicinaPovracaj,
       COUNT(DISTINCT otpis.mac) AS kolicinaOtpis,
       COUNT(DISTINCT razd.mac1) AS kolicinaRazd,
       sifr.min_kolicina AS minimalnaKolicina 
FROM ulaz_u AS ulaz 
       LEFT JOIN zaduzenje_u AS izlaz ON ulaz.mac = izlaz.mac 
       LEFT JOIN povracaj_u AS povracaj ON ulaz.mac = povracaj.mac 
       LEFT JOIN otpis AS otpis ON ulaz.mac = otpis.mac 
       LEFT JOIN razduzenje_u AS razd on ulaz.mac = razd.mac1 
       LEFT JOIN sifrarnik as sifr on ulaz.sifra = sifr.sifra 
WHERE ulaz.mac is not NULL 
      OR izlaz.mac is not null   
      OR povracaj.mac is not null 
      OR otpis.mac is not null 
      OR razd.mac1 is not null 
GROUP BY ulaz.sifra
```

The database is Mysql

My question is how to speed up the execution of queries?

warehouse:

- **serial number** => sifra
- **device name** => uredjaj
- **input** => ulaz (kolicinaUlaza)
- **output** => izlaz (kolicinaIzlaza)
- **return to the warehouse** => povracaj (kolicinaPovracaj)
- **dismantled** => otpis (kolicinaOtpis)
- **decommissioned with workers** => razd (KolicinaRazd)

Thank you

Comment: Can we see your question please?

Comment: Query plan please. Enough english to ask a querytion (which ends with "?"). Oh, and to start -reformualte it to get rid of all the distincts - those are generally "man, you slow everything down" parts and indicate a bad query to start with. And it helps to translate all words in teh query to english, you know.

Comment: Whats your database?Mysql and sql server are 2 different beasts.

Comment: What is ulaz' primary key? sifra? mac? Something else?

Comment: I'm new here and a little hard to get by! Sorry for my english :( 

The problem is the length of the execution of the query execution time is over (Query took 407.2486 sec) 

I request as a request to operate and gives accurate results al must be adapted and slightly accelerated.

Comment: What the heck is the WHERE clause supposed to do? For every record where ulaz.mac is NULL, all the other macs will be NULL, too. So you can reduce the whole WHERE clause to `WHERE ulaz.mac IS NOT NULL`, right? This may already speed things up :-)

Comment: Problem is that the primary alone id but not essential mac is unique in each table, all you have to count the number of times tables is a name('uredjaj') to appear?

Comment: So ulaz' primary key is id. There is also a column sifra and a column uredjaj. There can probably be different uredjaj per sifra, correct? (Otherwise the database would not be normalized.) You group by sifra and show with it one of its uredjajs. You count distinct non-null aluz.mac and how many of these can be found in izlaz, povracaj etc. Yes?

Comment: You might be a little clearer on this link you have a picture that shows what the result of the query: [link](http://www.skysign.rs/result.png) 

Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, you can reduce your select clause to `ulaz.mac IS NOT NULL`. The reason is that you want to have it guaranteed that at least one is not null. So when ulaz.mac is not null, the criteria is fullfilled. And when ulaz.mac is null then your join criteria is not met and all macs will be null consequently.

This can speed up the query, provided the dbms didn't detect this situation already. With the criteria reduced as mentioned, it is clear which part of ulaz must be read (and if you even have an index on it, this might be pretty fast). Of course the dbms must still join all those other tables. Again indexes on the macs could help.

```
SELECT CONCAT(ulaz.sifra, ' - ', ulaz.uredjaj) AS uredjaj,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ulaz.mac) AS kolicinaUlaza,
       COUNT(DISTINCT izlaz.mac) AS kolicinaIzlaza,
       COUNT(DISTINCT povracaj.mac) AS kolicinaPovracaj,
       COUNT(DISTINCT otpis.mac) AS kolicinaOtpis,
       COUNT(DISTINCT razd.mac1) AS kolicinaRazd,
       sifr.min_kolicina AS minimalnaKolicina
FROM ulaz_u AS ulaz
LEFT JOIN zaduzenje_u AS izlaz ON ulaz.mac = izlaz.mac
LEFT JOIN povracaj_u AS povracaj ON ulaz.mac = povracaj.mac
LEFT JOIN otpis AS otpis ON ulaz.mac = otpis.mac
LEFT JOIN razduzenje_u AS razd ON ulaz.mac = razd.mac1
LEFT JOIN sifrarnik AS sifr ON ulaz.sifra = sifr.sifra
WHERE ulaz.mac IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ulaz.sifra;
```

An alternative would be to pre-aggregate. First select all macs to see in which tables they are present. You are not interested in how often, but only whether yes or no. You test this with EXISTS which should be very fast provided there are indexes on the macs. Then you need distinct sifra + mac from ulaz. Join these and sum the existence counter up.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(ulaz.sifra, ' - ', ulaz.uredjaj) AS uredjaj,
  COUNT(*) AS kolicinaUlaza,
  SUM(macs.is_islaz) AS kolicinaIzlaza,
  SUM(macs.is_povracaj) AS kolicinaPovracaj,
  SUM(macs.is_otpis) AS kolicinaOtpis,
  SUM(macs.is_razd) AS kolicinaRazd,
  sifr.min_kolicina AS minimalnaKolicina
FROM 
(
  SELECT sifra, mac, uredjaj 
  FROM ulaz_u 
  WHERE mac IS NOT NULL
  GROUP by sifra, mac
) AS ulaz
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    ulaz_macs.mac,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select * FROM zaduzenje_u AS izlaz WHERE ulaz_macs.mac = izlaz.mac) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_islaz,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select * FROM povracaj_u AS povracaj WHERE ulaz_macs.mac = povracaj.mac) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_povracaj,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select * FROM otpis AS otpis WHERE ulaz_macs.mac = otpis.mac) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_otpis,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (select * FROM razduzenje_u AS razd WHERE ulaz_macs.mac = razd.mac) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_razd
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT mac FROM ulaz_u) AS ulaz_macs
) AS macs ON macs.mac = ulaz.mac
LEFT JOIN sifrarnik AS sifr ON ulaz.sifra = sifr.sifra
GROUP BY ulaz.sifra;
```

This may be faster or not. MySQL is known for being fastest with joins. However, the exists clause is closer to what we are looking for and we save many joins and their large intermediate result. Well, just try.

Comment: OLD query: Showing rows 0 - 14 ( 15 total, Query took 458.7143 sec) NOW Showing rows 0 - 14 ( 15 total, Query took 254.9191 sec) well done, Thank you